# EditableTextBlock - TreeView - Virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, virtualization

for the past couple of weeks I've been trying to get the EditableTextBlock (from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31592/Editable-TextBlock-in-WPF-for-In-place-Editing)) working on my TreeView.

The control has a property `IsInEditMode` which when set to true changes it to a `TextBox`.

The `TreeView` is virtualized and declared as follows:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeEnvironment"
          Margin="0,29,0,0" BorderThickness="0"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
</TreeView>
```

The `TreeView` uses the `ItemsSource` property to get it's data and the value of this is always a single instance of a class (lets call it `A`). This class contains a list of instances of another type (lets call it `B`). And this last class contains a list of instances of yet another class (lets call it `C). This is how it looks like in the code:

```
class A
{
        public String Name;
        public ObservableCollection<B> Items;
}

class B
{
        public String Name;
        public ObservableCollection<C> Items;
}

class C
{
        public String Name;
        public bool IsRenaming;
}
```

For each of these three classes there is an `HierarchicalDataTemplate` defined in `MainWindow.Resources` as follows:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type C}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Rename" Click="C_Rename_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>

        <v:EditableTextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" IsInEditMode="{Binding Path=IsRenaming, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type B}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, Mode=OneWay}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type A}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, Mode=OneWay}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="icons/icon_A.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

None of the `DataTemplate` have keys so that it is applied automatically.

The event that is triggered when the rename `MenuItem` of `C`'s context menu is clicked, is defined as follows:

```
private void C_Rename_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    C instance = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as C;

    if (instance != null) {
        instance.IsRenaming = true;
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("DEBUG: C_Rename_Click(" + sender.ToString() + ", " + e.ToString() + ") : instance == null");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `EditableTextBlock` does not turn into a `TextBox` when the `IsRenaming` property is set to true on the instance of `C` that was chosen to be renamed.

The `EditableTextBlock` works just fine when I place it as a normal control.

My guess is that it has to do with virtualization. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time, best regards,

100GPing100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class `A`, `B`, `C` need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for any changes made to them to be propagated to the UI. You can either implement it in each class individually or have a base class implement INPC and derive your classes from this base class.

Something like:

```
public class MyBaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}

public class A : MyBaseViewModel {
  private string _name;
  public string Name {
    get {
      return _name;
    }
    set {
      _name = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
  }

  private ObservableCollection<B> _items;
  public ObservableCollection<B> Items {
    get {
      return _items;
    }
    set {
      _items = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
  }
}

public class B : MyBaseViewModel {
  private string _name;
  public string Name {
    get {
      return _name;
    }
    set {
      _name = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
  }

  private ObservableCollection<C> _items;
  public ObservableCollection<C> Items {
    get {
      return _items;
    }
    set {
      _items = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
  }
}

public class C : MyBaseViewModel {
  private string _name;
  public string Name {
    get {
      return _name;
    }
    set {
      _name = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
  }

  private bool _isRenaming;
  public bool IsRenaming {
    get {
      return _isRenaming;
    }
    set {
      _isRenaming = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("IsRenaming");
    }
  }
}
```

Now when you change `IsRenaming` in your code, you will see the update propagate to the UI and the `TextBlock` switch to a `TextBox`.

**Side-note**

Please have a look at MVVM. If you're not sure about it. Get to learn it slowly cos it helps UI development in WPF quite a bit.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot, not only with this problem but also letting me understand MVVM better. Appreciate it :D